# Convert JSON to HTML: Uncaught TypeError: json.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to convert JSON to HTML to display it on website. I've googled, and this error occurs when when `json` is a string, and first I need to parse. But when I use `JSON.parse`, the console says it is already an object (`Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {  
    $.getJSON("http://quotes.rest/qod.json", function(json) {
      var html = "";

      json.forEach(function(val) {
        var keys = Object.keys(val);

        html += "<div class = 'blabla'>";

        keys.forEach(function(key) {
          html += "<b>" + key + "</b>: " + val[key] + "<br>";
        });

        html += "</div><br>";
      });

      $(".message").html(html);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `json` is an object, not an array - there is no `forEach` method on it.

Answer (score 6):

`json` is an object, not an array. You can use `forEach` only on arrays.

As you have done already, you can iterate over the object's keys like this:

```
Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = json[key];
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what everyone else said, it appears that the JSON response does not look like you think it does.

```js
var json = {
    "success": {
        "total": 1
    },
    "contents": {
        "quotes": [{
            "quote": "It's not whether you get knocked down, it...s whether you get up.",
            "length": "65",
            "author": "Vince Lombardi",
            "tags": [
                "failure",
                "inspire",
                "learning-from-failure"
            ],
            "category": "inspire",
            "date": "2016-08-09",
            "title": "Inspiring Quote of the day",
            "background": "https://theysaidso.com/img/bgs/man_on_the_mountain.jpg",
            "id": "06Qdox8w6U3U1CGlLqRwFAeF"
        }]
    }
};

var messageEl = document.querySelector('.message');
messageEl.innerText = json.contents.quotes[0].quote;
```

```html
<div class="message"></div>
```

Comment: I am working on this same exact problem and this code works great. Can you explain how you came up with the answer?

Comment: I grabbed the URL that was in the question and plopped it into a browser to see what JSON gets returned. `http://quotes.rest/qod.json`

If you can't do that for whatever reason, use `console.dir()` to dump the response into the console so you can see what the object looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJson` already transforms a JSON object into a javascript object, so you would not need to parse it again.

However, your problem starts with `forEach`, which is an Array method, not an Object method, therefor it will not work in your use case.

`var jsonKeys = Object.keys(json); jsonKeys.forEach(...)` will work, as `Object.keys` returns an array of Object keys.